# Drupal 8: how can I "eager load" Entities referenced via EntityReferenceFieldItemList field

Tags: 8, entities, database

*Note: this is my first Drupal project as I am usually working with Laravel.*

I have some entities `my-nodes` that have a field EntityReferenceFieldItemList (a multi-select linking to other entities of another content type `related-nodes`).

I want to query the `my-nodes` entities together with the related entities in 1 query (in Laravel I would describe this as eager loading the relationship).

The `my-nodes` entities all reference different `related-nodes` entities and I need to access `related-nodes` related values.

I'd like to optimize the amount of calls to the database to possibly only 1.

Method `referencedEntities` does not look like what I need because it's lazy loading, not eager loading:

```
$node->get($field)->referencedEntities();
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Laravel queries are pretty much the same as in Drupal. To eager load you join the tables and query the fields you are interested in. The method referencedEntities() is simply a method specific to the class mentioned, so only can be used after you've retrieved the parent node of the field, so it can only be lazy.

Comment: Before you try to build a query for referenced entities, I would first build this in a View and see how Views puts together this query, because there are more than two tables involved when you have added the field to a content type (bundle field).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exist in Drupal, you can't load entities of different types at once, the best you can do is load all referenced entities of the same type at once, which is what referencedEntities() does.

Each entity type has its own storage handler which doesn't know anything about other entity types, as far as those handlers are concerned, those other entities might not even be in the database but stored in MongoDB or text files.