# Get field value from multiple entities at once

Tags: entities, 9

I have a Drupal site using [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) in which one of the content types, let's call it a `Group`, can contain any number of paragraphs, and each of these paragraphs, let's call them `Members`, contains a reference to a user. I want to get all the `uid`s of users which are `Members` of a given `Group`.

I could accomplish this with a query of the database like

```sql
SELECT field_user_target_id
FROM paragraph__field_user
WHERE entity_id = (
    SELECT field_members_target_id
    FROM node__field_members
    WHERE entity_id = <GroupID>
    LIMIT 1
);
```

for a given `GroupID`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this efficiently without directly querying the database. One option would be something like

```php
$group = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($groupID);
$uids = [];
foreach ($group->field_members->referencedEntities() as $member) {
    $uids[] = $member->field_user->target_id;
}
```

but is there a way to do this without having to loop through the `Members`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreach loop is how I would do it, but to your point, a query will usually  be the most efficient. This technically applies in any situation where you have an API layer in between. If you would rather craft a query you can do so, but generally is not required. When profiling you application, if this area becomes a bottleneck, that is when I would start considering doing something like that. Note that using the API handles things like revisions and all that other stuff.

See [Drupal 8: how can I "eager load" Entities referenced via EntityReferenceFieldItemList field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245583/drupal-8-how-can-i-eager-load-entities-referenced-via-entityreferencefieldite) for further details. In that post they explain that using `referencedEntities()` loads those entities into memory, so it is not like these are individual hits on the database.